# Implemet ICEPush 0.5.5 in Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin, add-on, icepush

I am trying to add the ICEPush add-on to my Vaadin 7 project. But, I couldn't find any correct way to implement it.

I added this to my web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ICEPush for Portlets</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ICEPush for Portlets</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The class `org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPushServlet` seems to be unavailable. so I changed it to `org.icepush.servlet.ICEpushServlet`.

I use Vaadin 7.0.4 and ICEPush 0.5.5.
Can someone guide me how to implement ICEPush in Vaadin 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you also add the Maven/Ivy dependency and the repository?

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
   <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
   <version>0.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```

**Ivy:**

```
<dependency org="org.vaadin.addons" name="icepush" rev="0.5.5" />

<ibiblio name="vaadin-addons" usepoms="true" m2compatible="true" root="http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" />
```

If this is not the solution, we need more informations about the problem to help you.